# Is a continuous function >0 and defined on an open interval bounded by a constant?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

If g is continuous on (a,b) and g(x) > 0 for all x ∈ (a,b), then there is some constant M > 0 such that g(x) ≥ M for all x ∈ (a,b).

True or False?

I think this is false since g is defined on an open interval and is bounded below by 0, but not necessarily some M. Not sure how to show though

Comment: If you think the statement its false, then try to show an example of a function not bounded above.

Comment: There's a counterexample that you're familiar with. Think about how a function could rise without limit as $x$ nears zero.

Comment: That function would be 1/x, correct?

Comment: $x^2$ on $(0,1)$ is positive, but does not admit any uniform positive bound from below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the from the Completeness Property of $\mathbb{R}$ that every non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is bounded below has an infimum in $\mathbb{R}$. Since $g(x)>0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$ then $g$ is bounded below. Can you finish it from here? Hint: show that $\text{Range}(g)$ is not empty and is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then choose its infimum by the Completeness Property of $\mathbb{R}$.